# Request.Cookies is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies

I have been struggeling with a strange problem, if I may say so.

I have a controller in which I set a cookie, via this code:

```
var cookie = new HttpCookie("CookieName")
            {
                Value = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(12),
                Secure = false,
            };

            Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

This cookie is being set correctly (I guess), because I see this cookie in my Chrome and also in FireFox in the console.

I also have a piece of code that checks whether or not the specific cookie is set:

```
    var token = Request.Cookies.Get("CookieName");
    if (token == null)
    {
       //Create a new cookie
    }
```

Also tried this:

```
var token = Request.Cookies["CookieName"]?.Value;
```

But nothing, when I check with my debugger I see that the Request.Cookies contains nothing! I just don't understand this.

I use VS2015 Community and I have my project set up to be started via IIS10, developing on WIndows 10 Pro - 64-bits
I stopped using IIS Express because I thought the problem was being caused by the fact the url was like http://localhost:2322, I now work on a url which I let to 127.0.0.1 via my Host file on windows. domainA.local for example.

Added my web.config:

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6"/>
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1"/>
<httpCookies domain="" httpOnlyCookies="true"/>
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880"/>
</authentication>
```

Also tried this while authentication was commented

---

Update 26-02-2016:
I will try to explain my question in a different way.

I have a VS2015 project, an ASP.NET MVC C# application. This application should be listening to multiple URL's. Let's say it should listen to www.domainA.com and www.thisdomainiscool.com. Both domains are put in windows host file to 127.0.0.1. Because I run IIS on port 80 they both redirect to my project.

In my code I check via Request.Cookies["cookieName"] if the cookie exists. I also check the Url in Request and see that it is one of the specified URL's. According to each url I load a different style. I check this by `httpContext.Request.Url.Host` BUT although the URL is given, the cookies are not. Anytime the cookies are empty but I see them in my console of Chrome, but not in Fiddler. How can I make this work? In Fiddler I only see localhost:54121. Do I need to assume that this is the correct address? If I navigate to this URL I get a 404.

I hope this explanation, makes a lot of sense, thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to explicitly set the CookieDomain as an empty string?

Comment: You mean in the webconfig or when I create HttpCookie in the controller?

Comment: var cookie = new HttpCookie("CookieName")
            {
                Value = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(12),
                Secure = false      ,
                Domain      = ""            
            }; 

Would be this, but nothing

Comment: Sorry, was worth a try...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is cookies are typically associated with **host names** not **IP address**.

When you add an item to your hosts files you are allowing IP stack to resolve IP addresses to host names.

When you set the cookie to a host name the browser resolves that host name and also treats that location in respect to cookies.

The web server (in this case Visual Studio) does not need to do this -- it is getting requests and it does not know what it's host name is.

In IIs there are settings you make in the configuration files to fix this - I've not used VS studio in a while so there may be another trick but the easy way to solve it is to set the cookie on the host that visual studio believes is the host.  You can see that in fiddler the response message.

so -- **localhost** or **127.0.0.1**

(While 127.0.0.1 is an ip address, you can set a cookie to a full 4 digit ip address because it does not cause a security issue.)

There really is no other way to solve this problem.

---

The best way to solve problems with cookies is to use fiddler.  Fiddler is a utility that was written years ago and has always been free.  Telerik purchased it but you can still get it for free at http://www.telerik.com/fiddler

With fiddler you can see the traffic to and from your browser and look at the cookies being sent from both sides -- you can also change them to perform tests.

I expect about 10 mins after installing fiddler you will know what the problem is -- this will be much more productive than all of us trying to guess.

Comment: Hi Hogan,

Haven't thought about using this, great suggestion thanks.

So I installed it, and the crazy part is that in both the request and response there are NO cookies? But why does FireFox sees them?

Also a crazy note, when I go to domain.local or domain.com as you will In Fiddler I see Localhost:63694....

Comment: why would you go to domain.local or domain.com -- this is the problem I expect because you need a domain for the cookie but you are testing it locally.

Comment: I used a domain because it also wasn't working on localhost:12321
Or IIS Express, I just don't get it, I see the cookies in my console webbrowser

Comment: every cookie is associated with a URL -- you should be able to see in both fiddler and the browser what the URL is.  They should be the same in both fiddler and the browser.  If they are not the same that is why you are not seeing the same results in both places.

Comment: Okay, I see what the error is, In fiddler the URL is localhost:53338 and I call the site by domainA.com. How can I make it work that I call domainA.com from my browser and the cookies are linked correctly? The site listens to multiple URL, and I thought that for each URL the cookies were tracked seperatly

Comment: When the site is running in visual studio you have to use localhost -- change your code so you can configure where the cookie is saved based on there the site is deployed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104569/discussion-between-leroy-meijer-and-hogan).

Comment: @LeroyMeijer -- that goes into consulting realm.  Make a good question and I might answer it.

Comment: added an extra explanation

Comment: That did, it, :) Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

This works for me,

```
var cookie = new HttpCookie("CookieName")
        {
            Value = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(12),
            Secure = false,
        };

        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

to add the cookie

```
if (Request.Cookies["CookieName"] == null)
{
    var cookie = new HttpCookie("CookieName");
    cookie.Value = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(12);
    cookie.Secure = false;
    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
}
```